# Bigquery SQL MAX() text value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

How to get the MAX of a text value in column A. I would like to and another where clause to show only one of the "FY20-Q4M#" (MAX value only)

Current Table

| YY-QQ_STATUS | Program |
| --- | --- |
| FY20-Q2_ACTUALS | XYZ |
| FY20-Q3_ACTUALS | XYZ |
| FY20-Q3_BUDGET | XYZ |
| **FY20-Q4M0** | XYZ |
| **FY20-Q4M1** | XYZ |
| **FY20-Q4M2** | XYZ |
| FY20-Q4_BUDGET | XYZ |
| FY20-Q4_OUTLOOK | XYZ |

Goal:

| YY-QQ_STATUS | Program |
| --- | --- |
| FY20-Q2_ACTUALS | XYZ |
| FY20-Q3_ACTUALS | XYZ |
| FY20-Q3_BUDGET | XYZ |
| **FY20-Q4M2** | XYZ |
| FY20-Q4_BUDGET | XYZ |
| FY20-Q4_OUTLOOK | XYZ |

````
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN UPPER(SCENARIO) LIKE '%ACTUALS%' THEN CONCAT(LEFT(FISCAL_YEAR,4) ,'-', QUARTER, '_ACTUALS')
        WHEN UPPER(SCENARIO) LIKE 'Q%M%' THEN CONCAT(LEFT(FISCAL_YEAR,4) ,'-', QUARTER, SUBSTR(SCENARIO,3,2))
        WHEN UPPER(SCENARIO) LIKE '%BUDGET%' THEN CONCAT(LEFT(FISCAL_YEAR,4) ,'-', QUARTER,  '_BUDGET')
        END AS SCENARIO,
CONCAT(LEFT(FISCAL_YEAR,4) ,'-', QUARTER) AS QUARTER,
PROGRAM_NAME,
FROM [XXXXFinance.FINANCE_OPS_REPORT_V] FIN  
WHERE PROGRAM_NAME = 'Kiev20'
    AND (XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER >= (SELECT XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER FROM [XXXXMaster_Data.CALENDAR] 
    WHERE CALENDAR_DATE_STR = CURRENT_DATE())
    OR XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER < (SELECT XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER FROM [XXXXMaster_Data.CALENDAR] 
    WHERE CALENDAR_DATE_STR = CURRENT_DATE()) AND (SCENARIO CONTAINS 'Actual' OR SCENARIO CONTAINS 'Budget')
    OR XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER < (SELECT XYZ_PER_NAME_QUARTER FROM [XXXXMaster_Data.CALENDAR] 
    WHERE CALENDAR_DATE_STR = CURRENT_DATE()) AND (SCENARIO CONTAINS 'Q%M%'))
group by 1,2,3
order by SCENARIO```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select 
    ifnull(format('FY%s-Q%sM%s', any_value(year), any_value(quartal), max(month)), any_value(YY_QQ_STATUS)) as YY_QQ_STATUS, 
    Program
from (
    select *, 
        regexp_extract(YY_QQ_STATUS, r'FY(\d\d)-Q\dM\d') year,
        regexp_extract(YY_QQ_STATUS, r'FY\d\d-Q(\d)M\d') quartal,
        regexp_extract(YY_QQ_STATUS, r'FY\d\d-Q\dM(\d)') month
    from `project.XXXXFinance.FINANCE_OPS_REPORT_V`
)
group by Program, ifnull(format('FY%s-Q%s', year, quartal), YY_QQ_STATUS)
```

if applied to sample data in y our question  - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of the values, you could use `row_number()` and choose one row:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(YY_QQ_STATUS, 7) order by YY_QQ_STATUS desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where not (YY_QQ_STATUS like 'FY20-Q4%' and seqnum > 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and I have added my SQL for reference,

Note: I have other years, not just 2020. I'm going back from 2016 to the current year etc.

And where would I place the row_number()? Do I incorporate this before the line "GROUP BY"?

Comment: @QuicKick . . . This query answers the question you asked, so this is where the `row_number()` goes.  No aggregation is needed, based on your question.  This can easily be extended to other years, but you specifically asked about one year:  "I would like to and another where clause to show only one of the "FY20-Q4M#" ".